# "Non-resolvable parent POM" with Play framework project using Maven

Tags: maven, playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm trying to compile a Maven project that works on one Ubuntu machine but doesn't work on another and I don't know why. It uses the Play Framework. The start of the pom.xml file for the project contains:

```
<parent>
<groupId>org.play</groupId>
<artifactId>play-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>
</parent>
```

When I run mvn install, I get this error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project ... pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find org.play:play-parent:pom:1.1 in 
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution
 will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or 
updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ 
line 5, column 11 -> [Help 2]
```

The Maven settings.xml file I copied over from the other machine contains:

```
 <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                          http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

<localRepository/>
<interactiveMode/>
<usePluginRegistry/>
<offline/>
<pluginGroups/>
<servers>
     artifactory ids, logins and passwords
    </servers>
<mirrors/>
<proxies/>
<profiles/>
<activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```

I have the play framework installed and ran "play install maven" as instructed to install the play maven module: http://www.playframework.org/modules/maven-1.0/home I'm assuming I need to tell Maven somehow where this module is. I don't want to modify the pom.xml file as it works as is on another machine and I'd rather solve this  in a nicer way.

Does anyone know what's wrong or have any hints on what I can do?

Comment: "The other machine has in its settings.xml file which I copied over to the other machine." - has *what* in its settings.xml file? If you want answers explaining your settings.xml file, you should include the contents of the file in the question :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing play-parent in your local maven repository. The page you linked instructs you to do `play mvn:init` to get that, so do that.

Apparently the command both installs the module to local repo *and* creates a new pom.xml file. If you don't want the latter to happen, I would think you can store your current pom and revert to that after `play mvn:init` has finished installing of play-parent in your local repo.

Comment: I get " Invalid command: mvn:init" when running that. I've done a search but can find no answers to why. It isn't clear on the page when you need to run command either. New projects only?

Comment: I made a dumb mistake; I thought I got it working but I was compiling the wrong project...

Comment: @BobSmith what does `play help mvn` say? That should list the options.

Comment: @BobSmith be it new or old project, you would need play-parent in your maven repo, and the error message you're getting (listed in the question) implies that you don't have it.

Comment: "play help mvn" says "Oops, command 'mvn' not found.". "play install maven" succeeds however. I get the same result on the machine things work on as well. So confused.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem and was able to fix it by copying my settings.xml to .m2 directory located in my root folder and doing "mvn clean install" on the project from terminal. Let me know if it helps.